# Bernoulli Process, how to define as independent trials

Tags: probability, bernoulli-numbers

Consider a Bernoulli Process(p). What is the probability you will get 5 heads before 3 tails, flipping a coin.

Im having trouble answering this question because, from my understanding Bernoulli process has to have independent trials, however a failure of say tosses 1-8 flips, directly affects 2-9 (you know atleast 3 tails in 1-8)

Comment: I would do it recursively.  Let $P(n,m)$ be the probability that you get $n$ Heads before you get $m$ tails.  Then $P(n,m)=\frac 12\times (P(n-1,m)+P(n,m-1))$ and it is easy to sort out boundary values.

Comment: aaah @lulu yes perhaps interpreting question wrong!

Comment: @Mehness  the way I read it, the game takes at most $7$ tosses.  After $7$ you must have either five heads or three tails.  So, it is perfectly possible to just sort out the various cases over $7$ trials.  My recursion, though, will handle much larger numbers.

Comment: On reflection, you can just assume that $7$ tosses are made (even if the game is over before then).  Your problem is the same as getting $≥5$ heads over seven tosses.

Comment: yeah sure on reflection eminently readable as actually terminating if 5 heads occur first rather than BC2 type thing (it's late)!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In order to obtain 5 heads before 3 tails you must obtain *at least* five heads among the first seven tosses.